# Couldn't match type ‘(Integer, [String])’ with ‘[String]’

Tags: haskell

Compiling this in GHCi:

```
splitLines:: String -> [[String]]
splitLines splitLinesStr = splitWords (lines splitLinesStr)

splitWords:: [String] -> [[String]]
splitWords splitWordList = tupleNums (map words splitWordList)

tupleNums :: (Enum a, Num a) => [b] -> [(a, b)]
tupleNums tupleNumList = zip [1..] tupleNumList
```

Gives the following error message:

```
Couldn't match type ‘(Integer, [String])’ with ‘[String]’

Expected type: [[String]]

Actual type: [(Integer, [String])]
In the expression: tupleNums (map words splitWordList)
In an equation for ‘splitWords’:
splitWords splitWordList = tupleNums (map words splitWordList)
```

Anybody know how to fix this type error? I'm a beginner at this so the pointers are helpful.

Comment: Yeah, remove `tupleNums`.

Comment: How can `splitWord` return a `[[String]]` if it calls `tupleNums`?

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? That information is required on this site in the text of any question seeking debugging help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with most *type errors* the error can be at the *caller* or the *callee*, in this case I suspect it is with the *caller*.

The most likely explanation is that you don't have to call `tupleNums`:

```
splitLines:: String -> [[String]]
splitLines splitLinesStr = splitWords (lines splitLinesStr)

splitWords:: [String] -> [[String]]
splitWords splitWordList = map words splitWordList
```

This simply works fine, you don't attach any "line numbers" (?) to your words.

---

Another possibility is that you failed to *update* the type of `splitLines` and `splitWords` properly when you started adding line numbers:

```
splitLines:: (Enum a, Num a) => String -> [(a,[String])]
splitLines splitLinesStr = splitWords (lines splitLinesStr)

splitWords:: (Enum a, Num a) => [String] -> [(a,[String])]
splitWords splitWordList = tupleNums (map words splitWordList)

tupleNums :: (Enum a, Num a) => [b] -> [(a, b)]
tupleNums tupleNumList = zip [1..] tupleNumList
```

**EDIT**

How to manipulate the type signature? Let's only discuss `splitWords` since the case for `splitLines` is equivalent. First let's take a look at the expression:

```
tupleNums (map words splitWordList)
```

with types:

- `splitWordList :: String` (the input);
- `words :: String -> [String]` (library);
- `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]` (library);
- `tupleNums :: (Enum c, Num c) => [d] -> [(c, d)]` (defined).

I've renamed `a` and `b` of `tupleNames` to `c` and `d` because of name clashes. Now how does Haskell reasons about the types?

It has to fill in `a` and `b` of `map`. Now because the first argument of `map` has type `a -> b` and `words :: String -> [String]`, this means `a = String` and `b = [String]`. By doing so, the `map` we use (so to speak) collapses to:

```
map words :: [String] -> [[String]]
```

now when we call this function on `splitWordList`, it further collapses to:

```
map words splitWordList :: [[String]]
```

Now the result of this expression will be a list of lists of `String`s.

Haskell furthermore needs to guess the type of `tupleNums`. Since it has signature: `(Enum c, Num c) => [d] -> [(c, d)]` and takes `map words splitWordList :: [[String]]` as the first parameter, this means that `d = [String]` (mind `c` is not `String`). So this collapses to:

```
tupleNums (map words splitWordList) :: (Enum c, Num c) => [[String]] -> [(c, String)]
```

It cannot/should not reason about `c` because the aim is to keep functions as generic as possible.

> **Note** (type inference): mind however that Haskell (most of the time) does not need to be given the type. It has a type inference system that will generate the *most generic type signature possible*. If you feed your compiler this file:
>
> ```
> splitLines splitLinesStr = splitWords (lines splitLinesStr)
>
> splitWords splitWordList = tupleNums (map words splitWordList)
>
> tupleNums tupleNumList = zip [1..] tupleNumList
> ```
>
> you can query the type Haskell has resolved with:
>
> ```
> *Main> :t splitWords
> splitWords :: (Enum a, Num a) => [String] -> [(a, [String])]
> ```
>
> If what you say makes no sense from a type-perspective, it will fail to compile. Types can be useful to keep track of the items yourself. There are a few (GHC) language extensions that can make the type system fail to find the most generic type or let it get stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: The 2nd code block is exactly what I needed, but can you explain what you are doing with the functions type signatures because I don't understand fully. Thank you!